# Custom Part in Orchard CMS--can access fields, but can't create item with this type

Tags: orchardcms

I made a custom part in an Orchard module, and on my Orchard site, it shows up as a custom part. In addition, when I create a new content item with this part, the fields of this part show up and I can enter in input. Unfortunately, when I go to save/publish this item, I get an error that "the page does not exist." Has anyone else run across this problem? My guess is a database error; since the part's types are all exposed on the site, I doubt that's the issue.

Comment: Show some code of the part (classes, migrations, handlers, drivers and views). There's very high probability that something in code is wrong - part's types might as well be shown since it's just outputted HTML that isn't tied with your part until you try to save it..

Comment: Check your logs (app_data\logs)